# In MySQL, what does the '+' operator do in the context of a boolean expression?

Tags: mysql, operators, boolean-expression

For example:

```
    IF (SELECT ((new.fieldA IS NULL) + (new.fieldB IS NULL) + (new.fieldC IS NULL)) <> 2)
    THEN
        do some stuff
    END IF;
```

I am coming to MySQL from PostgreSQL. I came across this syntax (in the select statement) and am having a hard time figuring out what exactly the '+' operators are doing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the boolean expressions will be treated as integers, with 0 representing false and 1 representing true.  Then, your select:

```
SELECT ((new.fieldA IS NULL) + (new.fieldB IS NULL) + (new.fieldC IS NULL)) <> 2
```

will be *true* if only one of the three A, B, C fields is non null, with the other two being null.  If all three are null, all are not null, or two are not null, then the condition would be false.